# Fear of thieves and Mukzeh on Shabbes w. Eruv and Yom Tov

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, muktzeh

If person justified fears thieves and wants to go outside and to keep by himself his valuables (money, passport, etc), that actually are mukzeh. Is there a way to do it on Shabbes in the place where there is an Eruv and on Yom Tov?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding Shabbat:**

In the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [סימן סח - דין תפלת הדרך ושאר דברים שצריכין לזהר בדרך](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0124_L5) it says:

> **סעיף י"ב:** מִי שֶׁהוּא בְּיוֹם שַׁבָּת קֹדֶשׁ בַּדֶּרֶךְ בַּמָּלוֹן וְיֵשׁ לוֹ מָעוֹת, אִם יָכוֹל לְהַפְקִידָן אוֹ לְהַצְנִיעָן, אָסוּר לְהַחֲזִיקָן בְּכִיסוֹ, שֶׁהֲרֵי הֵם מֻקְצֶה. וְאִם מִתְיָרֵא שֶׁמָּא יִגְנְבוּן מִמֶּנּוּ, יִתְפְּרֵן בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת בְּבִגְדּוֹ וְיֵשֵׁב בַּבַּיִת, וְלֹא יֵצֵא בָהֶן בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵין עֵרוּב. אַךְ אִם יֵשׁ לָחוּשׁ שֶׁמָּא מֵחֲמַת זֶה שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹצֵא כָּל הַיּוֹם מִבֵּיתוֹ, יַרְגִּישׁוּ שֶׁיֶּשׁ לוֹ מָעוֹת וְיִגְזְלוּן מִמֶּנּוּ, מֻתָּר לָצֵאת בָּהֶן כְּשֶׁהֵן תְּפוּרוֹת בְּבִגְדּוֹ. אֲבָל אִם הֵן בְּכִיסוֹ, בְּכָל עִנְיָן אָסוּר‏

If one has valuables that one is afraid will be stolen - and one is a hotel *in the middle of nowhere* with nowhere to safely store one's valuables - then one can sew them into one's clothes before Shabbat.

One may even walk outside wearing these clothes, if there is an Eruv.

If there is no Eruv then one may not go outside, unless - by staying inside - he's making it obvious that he's hiding valuables, and he risks being assaulted as a result.

**Yom Tov:**

The Kitzur does not mention this specific case for Yom Tov, but the laws of carrying on Yom Tov are that anything that is being carried for a purpose, is allowed to be carried without an Eruv, and anything can be carried if there's an Eruv.

Regarding carrying on Yom Tov the Kitzur in     [סימן צח - הלכות יום טוב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0097_L2) says:

> **סעיף ל"ד:** הוֹצָאָה, מֻתֶּרֶת בְּיוֹם טוֹב, אֲפִלּוּ מַה שֶּׁאֵינוֹ לְצֹרֶךְ אֹכֶל נֶפֶשׁ, **וּבִלְבַד שֶׁיְהֵא בָּהּ אֵיזֶה צֹרֶךְ אַחֵר** (כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתַבְתִּי בְּסָעִיף א'), אֲבָל שֶׁלֹּא לְצֹרֶךְ כְּלָל, אָסוּר לְהוֹצִיא כִּי אִם בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁמֻּתָּר לְהוֹצִיא בַּשַׁבָּת. וְגַם לְצֹרֶךְ אֹכֶל נֶפֶשׁ, כְּגוֹן כַּדֵי יַיִן, לֹא יִשָּׂא מַשָּׂא גָּדוֹל כְּמוֹ שֶׁהוּא עוֹשֶׂה בַּחֹל, אֶלָּא יְשַׁנֶּה. וְאִם אִי אֶפְשָׁר לְשַׁנּוֹת, כְּגוֹן שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ הַרְבֵּה אוֹרְחִים עוֹשֶׂה כְּדַרְכּוֹ‏

Regarding Muktzeh, the Kitzur in [סימן צט - דיני מקצה ביום טוב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0098_L2)  says that anything that is Muktzeh in Shabbat is Muktzeh on Yom Tov - and possibly even certain items not Muktzeh in Shabbat are Muktzeh on Yom Tov:

> **סעיף א':** כָּל מֻקְצֶה הָאָסוּר בְּטִלְטוּל בַּשַׁבָּת, אָסוּר גַּם בְּיוֹם טוֹב : ‏

So I assume the same "sew into your clothes" workaround would be valid on Yom Tov.

Comment: Why Kitzur writes וְיֵשֵׁב בַּבַּיִת if later he rules  לֹא יֵצֵא בָהֶן בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵין עֵרוּב? The later would be enough.

Comment: If you look in the older Kitzur, you will see that there is no comma after וְיֵשֵׁב בַּבַּיִת  - it says  יִתְפְּרֵן בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת בְּבִגְדּוֹ וְיֵשֵׁב בַּבַּיִת וְלֹא יֵצֵא בָהֶן בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵין עֵרוּב - which removes the redundancy, somewhat.